# npm run prod --watch single file?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, reload

I am working with VueJS and i18n internationalization.

I would like a npm run production triggering whenever the file is changed, so something like "npm run production -- --watch './vue-i18n-locales.v1.js'" -> watch if this file is changed. I know it's not the required method though!

All the words are in the file vue-i18n-locales.v1.js
This file is imported in app.js:

```
import VueInternationalization from 'vue-i18n';
import Locale from './vue-i18n-locales.v1.js';
```

I would like this file to be editable from an admin panel (through an interface). But I don't know how to get the changes directly (I would need to run npm run prod each time the file gets saved... or could/should I do this automatically?)

Do you have any suggestions maybe?

For now my option would be to create a batch file containing npm run prod, that I would execute when the file is saved...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick - added the translations json file in /public, and get its content from a axios call in app.js, so it's always refreshed without any action

```
axios.get('/i18n').then(
    response => {
        let Locale=response.data;
        i18n = new VueInternationalization({
           locale: lang || 'en',
           messages: Locale
        });
     }
);

Route::get('i18n', 'UtilsController@i18n');

public function i18n(){
    return file_get_contents ("translations.json");
}
```